# Return an array with response from Observable<{string; number; string;}[]>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I developp a app with Angular 9, and I want return an array with my response. In my service class I have this method,

```
 getReport(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
    return this.http.get<ReportReport>(
      `https://localhost:44354/report?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`,
      this.httpOptions);
}
```

My object return is Report

```
export interface Report {
  range: string;
  opens: number;
  closes: number;
}
```

And I would like getReport return an array like this.

```
 list= [
    {
      name: 'Opens',
      value: Report.opens,
      color: 'green',
    },
    {
      name: 'Closes',
      value: Report.closes,
      color: 'red',
    }
]
```

So i tried with a subscribe observable like :

```
 getReport(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
     return this.http.get<ReportReport>(
      `https://localhost:44354/report?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`,
      this.httpOptions).subscribe(result => { return [{
        name: 'Opens',
        value: result.opens,
        color: 'green',
      },{

        name: 'Closes',
        value: result.closes,
        color: 'red',
      }]
    });
}
```

with this method I have a subscription return.

and with a map

```
 getReport(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
     return this.http.get<ReportReport>(
      `https://localhost:44354/report?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`,
      this.httpOptions).pipe(map(result => { return [{
        name: 'Opens',
        value: result.opens,
        color: 'green',
      },{

        name: 'Closes',
        value: result.closes,
        color: 'red',
      }]
    }));
}
```

but its doesn't work with subscribe and map.

with this method I have a Observable<{name: string; value: number color: string;}[]> for the return
I just i would like this return  -> {name: string; value: number color: string;}[] not observable

So it's possible to do that ?  or/and How I can make this ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: No, it is not possible. You can't convert an asynchronous value to synchronous. You could make it into a promise and use async/await, but rather than that, embrace the observables. They are one of the best parts of Angular.

Comment: thank you for you response, sorry but i'm start with angular so I don't know make this. How i can ?

Comment: Why you do not want to return  Observable<{name: string; value: number color: string;}[]> ?

Comment: because i want initialize an array for my component and use a ngfor for display data

Comment: Use `of`: `this.httpOptions).pipe(map(result => { return of([{ ...`

Comment: this solution not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subscribe to the HTTP Observable in the controller and define your array there. Try the following

Service

```js
getReport(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
  return this.http.get<ReportReport>(`https://localhost:44354/report?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Controller

```js
public report: any;

this.reportService.getReport('...', '...').subscribe(
  response => {
    this.report = [
      {
         name: 'Opens',
         value: result.opens,
         color: 'green',
      },
      {
         name: 'Closes',
         value: result.closes,
         color: 'red',
      }
    ];
  },
  error => { // handle error }
);
```

And use it in the template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="report">
  <div *ngFor="let item of report"> 
    {{ item.name }}
    {{ item.value }}
    {{ item.color }}
  </div>
<ng-container>
```

Comment: Or to avoid memory leak can us | async in view

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use an async/await with promise

```
  async getReport(startDate: string, endDate: string){
    return await this.http
      .get<Report>(
        `https://localhost:44354/report?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`,
        this.httpOptions
      )
      .toPromise();
  }
```

```
getReports(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
    this.getReport('2020-03-20', '2020-03-26').then(response => {
      let lists= [
       {
        name: 'Opens',
        value: response .opens,
        color: 'green',
      },
        {
        name: 'Opens',
        value: response .opens,
        color: 'green',
      }];
    });
```

its possible to use the list outside the promise ? exemple if i want return list from my method getReport ?